# Python gives error when importing from PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-imaging-library, importerror

I accidentally deleted some important files for python when running scripts but I can't understand how to get these files back.
[image: Error]

Is there a way I can solve this?

Note that I already tried reinstalling both python 3.8.6 (through the installer downloaded from python website) and I tried to uninstall and reinstall marplotlib.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: To be clear this error keeps happening even after you reinstalled python and PIL in the new python?

Comment: I’m sorry, I didn’t know I could reinstall pillow. I did and now it got fixed. Thanks

Comment: Please add your stacktrace as text to the question, not as a image